# How can a browser know the scss files?

Tags: css, browser, sass

I see this [html template](https://freehtml5.co/preview/?item=learn-free-website-template-using-bootstrap-for-school-courses-websites), and inspect it using Chrome inspection tool.
I'm surprised to know that my browser can detect the scss files instead of the compiled css one.
Then, I push Ctrl+U to view the page source, try to find 'scss' but it gives nothing in result.
So, how does the browser know the scss files?

P.S. I'm new to scss/sass/css pre-processor things

Comment: Browses are programs. They are as smart as they have been programed to be. It looks for sources of `css` files and, if any, displays them instead, with option to switch to `css`. Browsers don't have AI. Yet.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu, You make no sense. What do you mean by "the browser looks for sources of `css` files and, if any, displays them instead, with option to switch to `css`"? Could you be a little more explicit?

Comment: @broken Note it is quite rude to tell people they make no sense, even if what they said makes no sense to you. Instead, you should say what they said makes no sense to you. It's a big difference. Hope it makes sense. *"Sources of `css`"* means the `scss` source file, based on the sourcemap present in the `css` file and displaying that `scss` file instead of the `css` outcome.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can read this article for more about Sourcemaps: https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/sourcemaps/

This is mainly used for debugging and most of the times is stripted from production environments (in this case I guess they left it for people to check the actual source code and learn as you did :P)

Comment: Link no longer works

Answer (score 5):

What you are seeing is called Sourcemaps. Sourcemaps allow you to see the original source instead of the compiled CSS. This is usually used for debugging.