# bootstrap class non recognized and non displayed in firebug

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am reading a book on bootstrap to learn it. I downloaded the bootstrap files and included them in my test file: test.html. The issue is that a class "navbar-toggle" is not recognized by my browser and not displayed in firebug. I tried to put the external link to access "bootstrap.min.css", I checked that this class does exist in this local and external file, but nothing works as expected. I have other issues with another class, for example with the "navbar-brand" class which is recognized in firebug but in the "_navbar.scss" file that comes from nowhere, and after having checked, this class is different from the one I should have in "navbar-brand.css". I take another example: The class "icon-bar" is not recognized and displayed in firebug. I can see in firebug that there are some css rules coming from the three files I included (bootstrap.min.css, bootstrap-grid.min.css, bootstrap-reboot.min.css) that are displayed in firebug, but not the three one I discussed above.

Here is the file test.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

<link href="./bootstrap-4.4.1-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link  href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" rel="stylesheet" media="all" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="./bootstrap-4.4.1-dist/css/bootstrap-grid.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="./bootstrap-4.4.1-dist/css/bootstrap-reboot.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Mon Logo</a>
            </div>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Lien actif</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Lien 2</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#">Lien 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./bootstrap-4.4.1-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./bootstrap-4.4.1-dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's your directory structure? where is bootstrap folder in your local directory?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're simply not looking at the mobile view? <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd> in FireFox if I'm correct and downsize to <768px.
[Guide on mobile view](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Responsive_Design_Mode)

On another note, you don't need the reboot and grid included if you already have the bundle. These files are used if you only require a reboot style (similar to a reset) or if you only use the grid to give your document structure.
[More info on Bootstrap grid](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/)
[More info on reboot and reset](https://css-tricks.com/reboot-resets-reasoning/)

Make sure the file path's to your assets (css, js, img, ...) are correct by monitoring the network tab in your developer tools (F12 in most browsers) or similarly check the console for 404 errors.
[Guide on network tab](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor)

On the scss files, I'm not entirely sure if you're watching the result on a local environment? It's a common practice to generate CSS files from SCSS and then pushing the generated files to your local environment. The browser doesn't need the SCSS files but lately is perfectly capable of handling them. In your developer tools are settings to disable sourcemaps and I believe that's what you're experiencing.
[plausible duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41343538/how-can-a-browser-know-the-scss-files)

For most of us this information comes by experience but I sense a bit this is what you need to move forward. So hopefully this is helpful to you.